# MvxRecyclerView is being drawn under other elements

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

#### What I have so far

I have a recyclerview and buttons below it. On initial state everything looks good: recyclerview makes space for a button and I can scroll down to the end of the list and the last item won't be hidden by the button. When I pick one of the items, one button becomes invisible and other buttons become visible.

#### Actual behavior

When buttons change their visibility, recyclerview fills parent, so part of the content is being hidden under the recently appeared buttons.

#### Expected behavior

I expect that recyclerview will shrink its height leaving some space for the buttons.

#### What I've tried to do

I've tried to apply this to a swiperefreshlayout:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

but now recyclerview will just disappear when first button hides and others show up.

#### Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar_actionbar" />
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center"
            android:maxLines="10"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            local:MvxBind="Text EmptyMessage;Visibility Visibility(ShowEmptyMessage)" />
        <MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4.MvxSwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/timeslotsSwipeRefresh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/getTimeslotButton"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
            local:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            local:MvxBind="Refreshing IsRefreshingTimeslots; RefreshCommand RefreshTimeslotsCommand">

    <!-- Here is my recycler view -->

            <MvxRecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/MyTimeslotsRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Timeslots;Visibility Visibility(ShowList)"
                local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_my_timeslot" />
        </MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4.MvxSwipeRefreshLayout>

    <!-- Here is my disappearing button -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/getTimeslotButton"
            android:text="Получить таймслоты"
            android:theme="@style/ButtonPrimary"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            local:MvxBind="Click GetTimeslotsCommand; Visibility InvertedVisibility(IsEditModeEnabled)" />

    <!-- Here are my appearing buttons. 
         I placed it inside of a relativelayout 
         to make a single visibility data binding -->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            local:MvxBind="Visibility Visibility(IsEditModeEnabled)">
            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/copyToSmsButton"
                android:text="Отправить по SMS"
                android:theme="@style/ButtonPrimary"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/copyToSmsButton">
                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:id="@+id/deleteTimeslotButton"
                    android:text="Удалить"
                    android:theme="@style/ButtonSecondary.Red"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:id="@+id/moveTimeslotButton"
                    android:text="Перенести"
                    android:theme="@style/ButtonSecondary"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Try change your  `MvxRecyclerView` and `MvxSwipeRefreshLayout` `layout_height` property form `match_parent` to `wrap_content`.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT Thanks for your reply! First, I want to try to rewrite layout using ConstraintLayout, managing visibility of several items with constraint group.